# Getting a list of CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION redirect URLs

Tags: php, curl

How can I get a list of URLs that CURL follows when loading a page with a CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION set to True?

I know there is a curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL) function, but that returns just the last URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work for you, which uses the `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` cURL option:

```
$locations = array();

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function($curl, &$header) use(&$locations) {
    $key = 'Location:';
    if (strpos($header, $key) === 0) {
        $locations[] = trim(substr($header, strlen($key)));
    }
    return strlen($header);
});
// ...
curl_exec($curl);
```

`$locations` will contain the URLs that cURL was redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `CURLOPT_HEADER` options and inspect the headers that were returned. Unfortunately this would require parsing out the location headers, as I don't know of a more direct way of getting the specific headers values out of returned content.

You might be just as well suited to turn off the option to follow redirects and manually make follow up cURL requests to follow the redirections, logging the redirection information along the way.